# going to next or previous frame in javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

So I am a bit new to javascript and I am looking to create a switch statement for keyboard functions relating to my animation. So if I were to click backspace it stops the animation, and when I click enter it resumes etc. That works but im also trying to get it to advance to the next frame or the previous frame when i click the left or right key, and it isn't entirely working. Sorry this is my first post but any suggestions or help would be great!

```
var roote = this;

addEventListener("keydown", controlBox);

function controlBox(evt){

switch(evt.keyCode){
case 8:
roote.box.stop();
break;
case 13:
roote.box.play();
break;

//previous frame
case 37:
roote.box.prevFrame();
break;
//next frame
case 39:
roote.box.nextFrame();
break;
}
}

var theFrame = document.getElementsByTagName("frame")[0];
var frameNumb = parseInt(theFrame, 10);



function prevFrame(){
roote.gotoAndStop((frameNumb) -1);
}

function nextFrame(){

roote.gotoAndStop((frameNumb) +1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myFrame = roote.currentFrame();
case 37:
roote.gotoAndStop(myFrame + 1); //go to next frame
break;
case 39:
roote.gotoAndStop(myFrame - 1); //go to previous frame
break;
```

answered my own question, was overthinking it.